# Repeating array elements in ListView cells issue Parse Server

Tags: android, arrays, database, listview

I have this piece of code that gets arrays of hashtags from a Parse server database based on each Post:

```
// Tags
List<String> tagsArray = new ArrayList<>();
if (pObj.getList(Configurations.POSTS_TAGS) != null) {
  tagsArray = pObj.getList(Configurations.POSTS_TAGS);
  Log.i(Configurations.TAG, "TAGS: " + tagsArray);


for (int i=0; i<tagsArray.size(); i++) {
    LinearLayout tagsLayout = finalCell.findViewById(R.id.cpTagsLayout);
    tagsLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    // Create Buttons
    final Button tButt = new Button(ctx);
    int height = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 44, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, height);
    lp.setMargins(3, 0, 3, 0);
    tButt.setLayoutParams(lp);

    tButt.setText(tagsArray.get(i));
    tButt.setTypeface(Configurations.osItalic);                                        tButt.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#777777"));                                        tButt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00000000"));
    tButt.setTextSize(10);
    tButt.setAllCaps(false);
    tButt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           String tag = tButt.getText().toString();
           Log.i(Configurations.TAG, "SELECTED TAG: " + tag);
        }});

    // Add button to the layout
    tagsLayout.addView(tButt);
       }// ./For loop
    }// ./ If
```

The app correctly gets the tag arrays while scrolling the ListView down, I know it by checking the Logcat:

```
I/log-: TAGS: [#quoteoftheday, #fun, #life]
I/log-: TAGS: [#breakfastinlove, #lifestyle, #pikkypic]
I/log-: TAGS: [#bigapple, #lifestyle]
```

Anyway, from the 3rd cell on, and even if I scroll my ListView up again, I get extra Buttons in the Scrollview of each cell, they are a sum of the previous arrays, so for instance, the 3rd cell shows the following buttons in a row:
**#quoteoftheday #fun #life #breakfastinlove, #lifestyle, #pikkypic, #bigapple, #lifestyle**

while it should show only:
**#bigapple #lifestyle**

The Logcat keeps showing the right arrays of tags, no matter where I scroll my ListView, so this means that each `tagsArray` is correctly fetched from the server.

How can I fix this weird issue?
Thanks!

Comment: did you close the for before tagsLayout.addView(tButt); ?

Comment: no @JoaquinAlvarez, the For loop close bracket is after tagsLayout.addView(), as you can see in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call removeAllViews for your tagsLayout before adding new TagsRow.
Check below corrected code:

```
List<String> tagsArray = new ArrayList<>();
if (pObj.getList(Configurations.POSTS_TAGS) != null) {
  tagsArray = pObj.getList(Configurations.POSTS_TAGS);
  Log.i(Configurations.TAG, "TAGS: " + tagsArray);

LinearLayout tagsLayout = finalCell.findViewById(R.id.cpTagsLayout);
tagsLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
tagsLayout.removeAllViews();

for (int i=0; i<tagsArray.size(); i++) {
    // Create Buttons
    final Button tButt = new Button(ctx);
    int height = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 44, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, height);
    lp.setMargins(3, 0, 3, 0);
    tButt.setLayoutParams(lp);

    tButt.setText(tagsArray.get(i));
    tButt.setTypeface(Configurations.osItalic);                                        tButt.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#777777"));                                        tButt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00000000"));
    tButt.setTextSize(10);
    tButt.setAllCaps(false);
    tButt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           String tag = tButt.getText().toString();
           Log.i(Configurations.TAG, "SELECTED TAG: " + tag);
        }});

    // Add button to the layout
    tagsLayout.addView(tButt);
       }// ./For loop
    }// ./ If
```

Comment: You're right, although I had to edit your code a little bit, you have to init LinearLayout tagsLayout = finalCell.findViewById(R.id.cpTagsLayout); before the FOR loop ;) Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Most Welcome :)